# How do I enter a timestamp in nanoseconds to influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am learning InfluxDB and looking to enter some data from SQL Server into Influx.

I take a timestamp and a price from SQL Server and convert the timestamp to EPOCH nanosecond and generate the correct influx line protocol:

[image]

The EPOCH timestamp has been calculated correctly when I check it on an external website:
[image]

I enter the line protocol text into influx as follows (and make sure that NANOSECOND is selected):

[image]

The data loads in fine.

When I go to inspect the data, I notice that it is rounded up to the nearest minute?

[image]

Is there a way to store the data as Nanosecond?